# How to extract the objects from an array to put them in variables automatically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables

How to extract the objects from an array to put them in variables that are created according to the index of the array that corresponds to the object

I tried it :

```js
response.forEach((el, i, )=>{

let nameProduct[i] = ` the name of product  : ${response[i].nameProduct}`;
console.log(nameProduct[i]);
});
```

but it's a fail

Comment: you could consider adding the full code if this is something you are just trying out. if the object is coming from the json, the json details would be useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the values to a global (or at least outside of `map`) variable.

```
const nameProduct = response.map(({ nameProduct }) => `the name of product: ${nameProduct}`);
```